# D3 v4 Bar chart shows 1 pixel wide bars

Tags: dc.js

I am new to all D3/react coding. I am converting D3 v3 example to D3 v4 (React-DC). I am able to convert for Pie chart and Row chart. But I am stuck at Bar Chart and Area Chart. It seems to be a minor issue, as I can see the rendered charts but with following issues (sorry in advance for a lengthy content):

1. Bar chart: The bars are 1 pixel wide. I checked on [DC js FAQ page in github](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ), they say I have to set xUnits. But, I have xUnits defined, but still it won't work.
2. Area chart (Stacked): Only shows one? I don't see the rest of the stacks.

I converted this working d3.js v3 example

```
<BarChart
  dimension={byYear}
  group={byYearGroup}
  x={d3.time.scale()}
  renderHorizontalGridLines={true}
  elasticX={true}
  xUnits={d3.time.years}
  ordinalColors={colors}
/>

<AreaChart
  dimension={byYear}
  group={rockByYearGroup}
  x={d3.time.scale()}
  renderHorizontalGridLines={true}
  elasticX={true}
  xUnits={d3.time.years}
  renderArea={true}
  stack={[popByYearGroup, funkSoulByYearGroup, electroByYearGroup, hipHopByYearGroup]}
  xyTipsOn={true}
  brushOn={false}
  ordinalColors={colors}
/>
```

Output: 
[image]

to this d3.js v4 example

```
<BarChart
  dimension={byYear}
  group={byYearGroup}
  x={d3.scaleTime()}
  renderHorizontalGridLines={true}
  elasticX={true}
  xUnits={d3.timeYears}
  ordinalColors={colors}
/>

<AreaChart
  dimension={byYear}
  group={rockByYearGroup}
  x={d3.scaleTime()}
  renderHorizontalGridLines={true}
  elasticX={true}
  xUnits={d3.timeYears}
  renderArea={true}
  stack={[popByYearGroup, funkSoulByYearGroup, electroByYearGroup, hipHopByYearGroup]}
  xyTipsOn={true}
  brushOn={false}
  ordinalColors={colors}
/>
```

Output:
[image]

These are my imports on the page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import crossfilter from 'crossfilter'
import {BarChart, AreaChart, PieChart, RowChart, ScatterPlot, SeriesChart} from './reactdc/react-dc'
import './reactdc/react-dc.css'
import albums from './data/albums'
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import dc from 'dc'
```

Also, I have converted the `coordinate-grid-mixin.js` to v4 standards:

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {compose, withProps} from '../utils'
import colorMixin from './color-mixin'
import marginMixin from './margin-mixin'
import baseMixin from './base-mixin'

const coordinateGridMixin = withProps({
  brushOn: PropTypes.bool,
  clipPadding: PropTypes.number,
  elasticX: PropTypes.bool,
  elasticY: PropTypes.bool,
  focus: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
  mouseZoomable: PropTypes.bool,
  //rangeChart??????
  renderHorizontalGridLines: PropTypes.bool,
  renderVerticalGridLines: PropTypes.bool,
  round: PropTypes.func,
  useRightYAxis: PropTypes.bool,
  x: PropTypes.any.isRequired, // TO DO : PropTypes.any d3 quantitive scale or ordinal scale
  xAxis: {
    propTypes: PropTypes.shape({
      orient: PropTypes.string,
      ticks: PropTypes.array,
      tickValues: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string, Date])),
      tickSize: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
      innerTickSize: PropTypes.number,
      outerTickSize: PropTypes.number,
      tickPadding: PropTypes.number,
      tickFormat: PropTypes.func
    }),
    setter(method, val){
      Object.entries(val).forEach(([key, value]) => method()[key](value))
    }
  },
  xAxisLabel: {
    propTypes: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.shape({
      labelText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      padding: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    })]),
    setter(method, val){
      if (val.labelText && val.padding){
        method(val.labelText, val.padding)
      }else{
        method(val)
      }
    }
  },
  xAxisPadding: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string]),
  xAxisUnit: PropTypes.string,
  y: PropTypes.any, // TO DO : d3 scale
  xUnits: PropTypes.func,
  yAxis: {
    propTypes: PropTypes.shape({
      orient: PropTypes.string,
      ticks: PropTypes.array,
      tickValues: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string, Date])),
      tickSize: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
      innerTickSize: PropTypes.number,
      outerTickSize: PropTypes.number,
      tickPadding: PropTypes.number,
      tickFormat: PropTypes.func
    }),
    setter(method, val){
      Object.entries(val).forEach(([key, value]) => method()[key](value))
    }
  },
  yAxisLabel:  {
    propTypes: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.shape({
      labelText: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      padding: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    })]),
    setter(method, val){
      if (val.labelText && val.padding){
        method(val.labelText, val.padding)
      }else{
        method(val)
      }
    }
  },
  yAxisPadding: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.number, PropTypes.string]),
  zoomOutRestrict: PropTypes.bool,
  zoomScale: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number), PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.instanceOf(Date))])
})

export default compose(coordinateGridMixin, colorMixin, marginMixin, baseMixin)
```

I am not sure what am I missing. There are not many v4 example on web either.

My library versions if it would help:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "crossfilter": "^1.3.12",
    "d3": "^4.13.0",
    "d3-scale": "^2.0.0",
    "d3-shape": "^1.2.0",
    "dc": "^2.1.9",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "recompose": "^0.26.0"
  }
```

**Update #1** 
I did some more digging and found that the following line of code in `dc.js` file return nothing.

```
var units = _chart.xUnits()(_chart.x().domain()[0], _chart.x().domain()[1], _chart.x().domain());
```

When I step into this line, it calls a range function (a modified version from newer d3.js (v.4.13.0) -> interval.js file) which is moved to `interval.js` file and expects `step` value as the last parameter.

```
interval.range = function(start, stop, step) {
    var range = [], previous;
    start = interval.ceil(start);
    step = step == null ? 1 : Math.floor(step);
    if (!(start < stop) || !(step > 0)) return range; // also handles Invalid Date
    do range.push(previous = new Date(+start)), offseti(start, step), floori(start);
    while (previous < start && start < stop);
    return range;
  };
```

as compared to this older version which works because the last parameter accepts an array

```
function range(t0, t1, dt) {
      var time = ceil(t0), times = [];
      if (dt > 1) {
        while (time < t1) {
          if (!(number(time) % dt)) times.push(new Date(+time));
          step(time, 1);
        }
      } else {
        while (time < t1) times.push(new Date(+time)), step(time, 1);
      }
      return times;
    }
```

Comment: I can't see anywhere where a value to `xUnits` is passed. If you are giving it a dynamic value, where do you get the value from ? Here's the link [for setting up this specific value](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md#dcunitsintegers)

Comment: Like in original example: they get it using `d3.time.years`. https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Intervals.md#years. I'm using this example: https://github.com/WaldoJeffers/react-dc